# PHP json_parse trakt API

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("http://api.trakt.tv/shows/trending.json/5d7588c188eeea0074b8d2664d12fffc");
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $result['title'][0];
echo "<br>";
echo $result['network'][0];
echo "<br>";
echo $result['air_day'][0];
echo "<br><img style='width:200px;' src='";
echo $result['images'][0]['poster'];
echo "'>";
?>
```

Ain't working. I don't know why.

I use the the trakt.tv shows API.

Comment: What exactly is the error/unexpected output?

Comment: `$result['title'][0]` is undefined ;) (Undefined index: title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
echo $result[0]['title'];
```

instead of

```
echo $result['title'][0];
```

Besides, PHP's echo function will print integers and strings, but will fail with array-alike structures. You could use var_dump or var_export instead. Thanks to them, you could scan the structure and you wouldn't ask this question ;)

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to write you a few days ago, but your answer is incredible, mate!